# How do I make the Unity Launcher background transparent?

Tags: unity, launcher

I found a way to make the icon backgrounds transparent for the Unity Launcher by changing the files under `/usr/share/unity/4`.

Does anyone know how to make the background transparent for the launcher itself? I already made it transparent under Compiz, but I want to remove the line that separates the launcher from the desktop. If anything, I just want to make it look like the icons are floating.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to remove the 1px white border around the launcher, right?
If that's the case, I *believe* it's hard coded and it's not something that can be achieved without messing up with unity source code, or in your case - with the unity-rotated one :)

Comment: thank you for your response. i was hoping that wasn't the case. :( when i removed the border around the icons, there were transparent .pngs with a border that were used as a border. I deleted them and replaced them with a purely transparent file of the same size and it removed the border. Maybe there is a .png of the "background" with the border for the entire launcher too?

Comment: Nope, there isn't one, at least not one that I know of :P

Comment: Well, given that, are there any good dock programs out there? :)

Comment: You can try Docky, DockBarX, Avant-Window-Navigator, Cairo-Dock etc... but don't you think that using Unity with a third party dock is a bit of a overkill? :)

Comment: Good point. :) I think I can just live with the little line